# MTG Masters Edition 2 &3 Release Notes

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there a online backup of the Masters Edition II FAQ (EN_MTGME2%20FAQ%20080918.txt from https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/masters-edition-ii-faq-2008-09-23) and Masters Edition III FAQ?

The WotC links seem to be broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find an archive of a lost web page, the first place you should always check is the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). Simply copy the URL you are looking for into the search bar, and you can see all of the copies they have by date. [Here is their most recent snapshot of that page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213154847/http://www.wizards.com/dci/downloads/EN_MTGME2%20FAQ%20080918.txt).